# How to ignore attributes when using yaml.dump?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pyyaml

I am trying to hide certain attributes when performing a YAML dump on an object.  I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773808/4589203) answer and it allows you to dump, but loading does not work.

```
import yaml
from copy import deepcopy

class SecretYamlObject(yaml.YAMLObject):
    hidden_fields = []

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        new_data = deepcopy(data)
        for item in cls.hidden_fields:
            del new_data.__dict__[item]
        return dumper.represent_yaml_object(cls.yaml_tag, new_data, cls,
                                            flow_style=cls.yaml_flow_style)

class Trivial(SecretYamlObject):
    hidden_fields = ["_ignore"]
    yaml_tag = u'!!Trivial'
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self._ignore = 3
```

Running this code

```
import yaml
yaml.load('!Trivial {a: 1, b: 2}')
```

I get the following error:

> ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag
>   '!Trivial'   in "", line 1, column 1:
>       !Trivial {a: 1, b: 2}

I've tried to 'hack' it so that yaml can find the constructor using a [classproperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191224/4589203) using something like this:

```
class SecretYamlObject(yaml.YAMLObject):
    # ... same as before... remove for brevity

class Trivial(SecretYamlObject):
    hidden_fields = ["_ignore"]

    @classproperty # decorator definition not shown here for brevity 
    def yaml_tag(cls):
        return ('!!')+'python/object:'+'{}.{}'.format(cls.__module__, cls.__name__)

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self._ignore = 3
```

This produces a bad yaml string:

```
import yaml
from secret_yaml2 import Trivial
print yaml.dump(Trivial())
```

> !%21python/object:secret_yaml2.Trivial {a: 1, b:
>   2}

For some reason, it converts the second `!` to `%21`... which again causes a constructor error.

BTW, The below works, but I would need to know the class of the object before loading the yaml, which I might not.

```
import yaml
from secret_yaml import Trivial
yaml.load(yaml.dump(Trivial()))
```

I'm trying to make a class which knows how to properly dump itself to yaml, but I can still load it through a normal yaml.load call.

Comment: The call to `load()` is not normal, it is unsafe, as it can construct arbitrary python objects, there is no excuse not to use `safe_load()`. Make sure your `Trivial` or `SecretYAMLObject` class have a `from_yaml` `class_method`, otherwise PyYAML doesn't know how to load the tagged mapping.

Comment: What I don't understand is, how would yaml know to USE that method?  You would first need to import 'Trivial' so it would be an option.  This is not the case with generic object serialization/de-serialization. The yaml is known to be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `__getstate__` which is used by both Python native pickle and PyYaml:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hidden = 42
        self.visible = 5

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        del state['hidden']
        return state

a = A()
d = yaml.dump(a)
print(d)
```

This prints:

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
visible: 5
```

This is the best way to ignore or hide attribute from serializers like PyYaml or Pickle.